# SQL query to search for string in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi i want to search for a particular string in a table stored in mysql database. The table structure is as follow:-

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    day    | 9-10    | 10-11  | 11-12    | 12-1  | 1-2    |  2-3   |  3-4 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Monday    | DA6210  | DA6220  | DA6010  |       | DA6020 |        |      |
| Tuesday   | DA6210  | DA6010  | DA6220  |       | DA6020 |        |      |
| Wednesday | IA6010  | DA6220  |         |       | DA6020 |        |      |
| Thursday  | IA6010  |         | DA6210  |       | GC6210 |        |      |
| Friday    | IA6010  |         | DA6010  |       | GC6210 |        |      |
| Saturday  | DA6210  |         |         |       |        |        |      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to search for the string against the day and all the time. For ex. if the day is thursday and code is DA6220 it should return empty set as the string is not there across all the time slots on thursday.

I have created an sql query but it is not working as desired. Kindly please provide a way to do it.

SQl query:-

```
SELECT * from `table` where day='Thursday' AND `9-10`='DA6220' OR `10-11`='DA6220' OR `11-12`='DA6220' 
            OR `12-1`='DA6220' OR `1-2`='DA6220' OR `2-3`='DA6220' OR `3-4`='DA6220'
```

Comment: "Not working as desired" does not really help. Describe exactly what happenes and what you would like to happen. For starters, though, try wrapping the whole part after AND in parentheses, so that it reads `SELECT * FROM table where day='Thursday' AND ( .. OR .. OR ..)`.
Moreover, your database is quite denormalized - you should probably have only three columns, named "day", "timeslot" and "content", and then a row for every non-empty day-timeslot combination.

Comment: [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) all your day columns together, then you can use [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to find it (or even `LIKE` if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * from `table` where day='Thursday' AND (`9-10`='DA6220' OR `10-11`='DA6220' OR `11-12`='DA6220' 
            OR `12-1`='DA6220' OR `1-2`='DA6220' OR `2-3`='DA6220' OR `3-4`='DA6220')
```

Looks like your AND is evaluated first. Please try the above

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it worked Kartikey

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem has been given, but when I look at your data I see something that can make your life a lot easier and increase your possibilities:
You would better to create a **VIEW**.

First of all, I have adapted slightly your columns names because you had reserved words.

[Click here for SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b5897/1)

**Introducing your new friend *myview***

```
cREATE VIEW myview AS 
SELECT wkday, '9-10'  AS rng, `9-10`  AS cd from `mytable` 
UNION  
SELECT wkday, '10-11' AS rng, `10-11` AS cd from `mytable` 
UNION 
SELECT wkday, '11-12' AS rng, `11-12` AS cd from `mytable` 
UNION 
SELECT wkday, '12-1'  AS rng, `12-1`  AS cd from `mytable` 
UNION 
SELECT wkday, '1-2'   AS rng, `1-2`   AS cd from `mytable` 
UNION 
SELECT wkday, '2-3'   AS rng, `2-3`   AS cd from `mytable` 
UNION 
SELECT wkday, '3-4'   AS rng, `3-4`   AS cd from `mytable`  
;
```

This is a one shot query against your DB.

Your view data is :

```
SELECT * FROM myview

wkday           rng     cd
----------------------
Monday      9-10    DA6210
Tuesday     9-10    DA6210
Wednesday   9-10    IA6010
Thursday    9-10    IA6010
Friday      9-10    IA6010
Saturday    9-10    DA6210
Monday      10-11   DA6220
Tuesday     10-11   DA6010
Wednesday   10-11   DA6220
...
```

---

Once your view is created, your original query is lot more simple to write :

**It becomes this :**

```
SELEct rng FROM myview WHERE wkday='Thursday' AND cd='DA6220';
```

No more ORs, no need to repeat endlessly the code you are looking for

...and if you want to search for more than one code, it's also peanuts:

```
SELEct rng FROM myview WHERE wkday='Thursday' AND cd IN ('DA6220','IA6010');
```

---

But what's cool with your new view is that you can ask as simply :

*What are the days or the ranges for which I have code 'DA6220' ?*

**days**

```
  SELEct wkday FROM myview WHERE cd='DA6220';
```

Results:

```
wkday
----------
Tuesday
Wednesday
Monday
```

**Ranges**

```
  SELEct rng FROM myview WHERE cd='DA6220';
```

Results:

```
rng
-----
11-12
10-11
10-11
```

This is a typical application of a VIEW. It makes your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE 0 < LOCATE("DA6220", CONCAT(
          `9-10`, " ", `10-11`, " ", `11-12`, " ",
          `12-1`, " ", `1-2`, " ", `2-3`, " ", `3-4`
       ))
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you don't have to repeat your search string repeatedly. It's probably *slightly* slower than the `OR` version.